# When does stripe actually deduct money from credit card

Tags: c#, webforms, stripe-payments

I am new in payment gateway; I can't seem to figure out when does a payment actually gets deducted. So once the all card details are successfull the code below gets executed:

```
public partial class Charge : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (Request.Form["stripeToken"] != null)
        {
            var customers = new StripeCustomerService();
            var charges = new StripeChargeService();

            var customer = customers.Create(new StripeCustomerCreateOptions
            {
                Email = Request.Form["stripeEmail"],
                SourceToken = Request.Form["stripeToken"]
            });

            var charge = charges.Create(new StripeChargeCreateOptions
            {
                Amount = 500,
                Description = "Sample Charge",
                Currency = "usd",
                CustomerId = customer.Id
            });

            Console.WriteLine(charge.Id);
        }

    }
}
```

what I noticed is that if I enter and email of test@gmail. without the "com" in the end, the code above gets executed, but it will say the email is invalid on Email = Request.Form["stripeEmail"].

so the question is does the money gets deducted when I get the token **Request.Form["stripeToken"]** or the money gets charged/deducted when I created a Charge via:

```
var charge = charges.Create(new StripeChargeCreateOptions
{
    Amount = 500,
    Description = "Sample Charge",
    Currency = "usd",
    CustomerId = customer.Id
});
```

Comment: Why would you expect money to get deducted when grabbing a value from the request? And what does the documentation say?

Comment: @mason the documentation says: "To charge a credit or a debit card, you create a Charge object. You can retrieve and refund individual charges as well as list all charges. Charges are identified by a unique, random ID."https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges  , the reason why I am confused is that test@gmail. was not flagged as invalid email prior to receiving a token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Stripe you create a token first either on its own, or as part of a [customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers) object. This token is only a reference to the card details. The token ID on its own is not enough to do anything with the card, Stripe just stores the encrypted card details.

When you issue the charge, this is when you say which card need to be charged with what amount. Prior to this the card details haven't even left Stripe's domain.

The reason you get this error on Charge is simple - email only gets validated at that point. Prior to that it's the card details that get validated and stored as a token.